# Amazon EC2 Linux AMI: What is the third column of yum list installed?

Tags: linux, centos, amazon-ec2, yum

Output of `yum list installed`, rightmost column:

Most of them say `installed`, some say `@amzn-main`, and some say `@amzn-updates`.

What is the meaning of this? It says `tmux` is `@amzn-main`, but I have been running it. So is it actually installed or not?

I'm trying to compile `zsh` 5.0.2, but its configure script is complaining about not finding `ncurses`. `ncurses` is listed as `@amzn-updates`. I have been looking around the system for its files without much luck, and `sudo yum install ncurses` gives me

```
Package ncurses-5.7-3.20090208.11.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

Answer (score 1):

The third column is which repository the package is installed from. All packages listed are installed. However, sometimes if there is more than one version available from different repositories, it will list which repository. Sometimes using `yum list installed` there is an annoying `installed` instead of an actual repository.

Here are some ways of discovering the repository for a given installed package:

```
rpm -qi {packagename}
```

or

```
repoquery -i {packagename}
```

References:

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/add-repositories.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635869/can-yum-tell-me-which-of-my-repositories-provide-a-particular-package

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with EC2, but since it based on CentOS, I guess that it is the repo id. You can list all configured repositories by running:

```
yum repolist all
```

> I'm trying to compile `zsh` 5.0.2, but its configure script is
>   complaining about not finding `ncurses`

Sounds like it complains about the header files and libraries, so you probably want to install `ncurses-devel`:

```
sudo yum install ncurses-devel
```

Comment: Okay, but does it mean that it is actually installed? What repo do the packages marked `installed` come from?

Comment: Install `yum-utils` then run `repoquery -i ncurses`, it will tell you where `ncurses` come from.

Comment: Yeah it looks like the reason that `zsh`'s `configure` failed to find `ncurses` was that it's installed in the somewhat non-standard `/lib/` dir instead of `/usr/lib/` or wherever. Still scratching my head about this (maybe I just gotta put some symlinks in `/usr/lib`), but I really am already spending too much time trying to set up an environment which is really realistically a transient one anyway.

Comment: Don't want to ask the same question again. Hence the comment. What is the difference between `@amzn-main`, `@amzn-updates` and `installed`?